# Including personal details in JWT

Tags: jwt

What is the best practice concerning including details about the user in the Authorization headers JWT? Should the JWT include the user's details such as name, mobile phone number, and email or should they be queried to a backend service?

What factors should be considered before making a decision about what details should be included in the payload of the JWT?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how your backend is designed.

If your user data is just an email address and a password, you obviously just store the email address in the jwt. But if on of your routes need some additional user data (e.g. phone number) to resolve some dependencies in your database, you could store the phone number in the token as well to avoid server load (because you dont have to perform a database query for the phone number of the user anymore).

If you have a more complex permissions structure, i would store the permissions role to the jwt as well, then you can easily check if the user is authorized to access this route and so on.

This is a pretty common answer, in the end, you have to decide what you need in your token.

There is one last thing (i guess you know it already): don't store the user's password in the token.